# Error while publishing Lightswitch application remotely from Windows 7 PC to Windows 2003 Server having IIS 6.0

Tags: iis-6, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012, windows-2003-webserver

I am trying to publish a Light Switch 2012 application as Web Application from Windows 7 PC to Windows 2003 IIS server, .Net Framework 4.0

The publish Summary as follows

Application Name - User Test

Application Version - 1.0.6.0

Application Type : Browser

Application Server : IIS Server

Authentication : Windows Authentication

Database : Do not publish

---

Error details while publishing with the option "IIS server has lightswitch deployment prerequisites installed".

============================================================================

102 Web deployment task failed. (15/04/2014 16:24:51) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.)

(15/04/2014 16:24:51) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer. The entry type 'unknown' was not expected at this time. The serialization stream may be corrupted.

---

When published without the option "IIS server has lightswitch deployment prerequisites installed".

the applications publishes successfully, But when the application is accessed from Browser it says authentication error.

I have searched a number of blogs with the same issue, but none have answered.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From the errors you can conclude :

1. Your server does not have lightswitch deployment prerequisites installed.
2. There is a problem with authentication.

You must further investigate what authentication problem occurs. As the question is now, there is no way to guess what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following steps to workaround the authentication error.
Keep the option in the publish wizard i.e "IIS server has lightswitch deployment prerequisites installed". and

1.In publish wizard choose the option "Yes,Create an application
    Administrator"    and mention your login credentials. 
 2.Make sure you have rights on the database that you supplied while deploying
    the application. for example I use "sa" account to deploy the
    database.
 3.In webconfig file, makesure you are the admin to the app.
   /*     !-- If no admin user exists, create an admin user with this user name->
        add key="Microsoft.LightSwitch.Admin.UserName" value="DOMAIN\EMPID" /> 
*/
     4. Assuming If you are able to deploy the application with no errors and still            get the get authentication info or load error, check the table called [dbo].[aspnet_Applications] in the deployed database and makesure
    your app name mentioned in the table data.If not the issue is with
    database permissions. 
5.Makesure your UserID shown up in the table [dbo].[aspnet_Users]

Hope this information helpful :)